# Change Properties of Form form1 with "this" but not Form1

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

Inside this scope,

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //Change Form1 properties here
        }
    }
}
```

If **change Properties** DoubleBuffered via either

```
Project1.Form1.DoubleBuffered = false;
```

or

```
Form1.DoubleBuffered = false;
```

then happen error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.DoubleBuffered.get'

But, if change via

```
this.DoubleBuffered = false;
```

then **the error is solved**. I mouse hovered the ***this*** and it showed

```
class Project1.Form1
```

Can anyone explain why **'this'** keyword represent the Project1.Form1 but I have error if I replace 'this' with Project1.Form1 or Form1? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `this` keyword refer to current instance of `Form1`. And explicitly mentioning `Form1` means you are referring to `Form1` as class name.

All properties that is not declared as `static` associated to instance of the class, not the class it self. Hence, you can only access the property from the class instance.

That behavior is make sense because you can have more than one instance of `Form1` each can have different value of `DoubleBuffered` property :

```
var instance1 = new Form1();
var instance2 = new Form1();
instance1.DoubleBuffered = true;
instance2.DoubleBuffered = false;
```

Comment: I tried to put your sample codes into the scope I mentioned in title, I have An unhandled exception of type **System.StackOverflowException** occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll for this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font; in InitializeComponent(). May be you just use them for explanation? thanks

Comment: yes, I meant that for explanation only. The correct way to set `DoubleBuffered` property in your case is by using `this` keyword, as you already know.